# Raspberry Pi 4, audio on hdmi 0, video on hdmi 1

Tags: audio, hdmi

Presently I am trying to setup a Raspberry Pi 4 to send its 7.1 uncompressed audio to an older home theater receiver for decoding via the HDMI 0 output and a 4k video output from the HDMI 1 output to a television.  I haven't found a configuration yet that works and am wondering if it is even possible.